# How to test a angular service function that returns a JSON?

Tags: json, angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a service written in angular that takes JSON as input and returns a JSON as output after performing some operations.

I had written a positive testcase to test this service. But its failing all the time.

The reason that I suspect for this failure is:

Expected Output :

```
[ Object({ key: 'Port', values: [ Object({ key: '01/01/17', values: [ Object({ date: '01/01/17', Type: 'Port', Result Code: '2', volume: '20', source: 'PCN', phone_Type: null }), Object({ date: '01/01/17', ....
```

Actual Output :

```
[{"key":"Port","values":[{"key":"01/01/17","values":[{"date":"01/01/17","Type":"Port","Result Code":"2","volume":"20","source":"PCN","phone_Type":null},{"date":"01/01/17","Type":"Port","Result Code":"3","volume":"60","source":"PCN","phone_Type":null}....
```

This is because of the presence of **Object**
keyword in expected output.

How can I resolve this?
I am using karma and jasmine for test cases and the service is written in angular4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to compare a JSON encoded Object (ie- a string) with a JavaScript Object. Your test probably looks something like this:

```
let jsonString = invokeMyService();
let expectedObject = { ... };
expect(jsonString).toEqual(expectedObject);
```

You need to make sure that your `jsonString` is parsed before comparing it to the object.  You need to call `JSON.parse()` like this:

```
let jsonString = invokeMyService();
let expectedObject = { ... };
expect(JSON.parse(jsonString)).toEqual(expectedObject);
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me with slight modifications as instead of 'JSON.parse' I need to use 'JSON.stringify' as I was getting error "unexpected token 'o' at position 1".